# PHP and Mysql Permission system

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i was wandering how i could make this work.

```
if ($accounttype == a) {
      print('Member')
     }
      elseif ($accounttype == b) {
        print('Moderator')
      }
      elseif ($accounttype == c) {
        print('Admin')
      }
      else {
        print('No rank') 
      }
```

Comment: Use semi-colons at the end of your statements

Comment: Also a [`switch()`](http://php.net/switch) might come in handy here

Comment: @QuestionGiver Brackets aren't semi-cola ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
 if ($accounttype == 'a') {
    print 'Member';
 } elseif ($accounttype == 'b') {
    print 'Moderator';
 } elseif ($accounttype == 'c') {
    print 'Admin';
 } else {
    print 'No rank';
 }
```

You need use strings in a quotes, and don't forget semicolons `;` at the end of line

Comment: What is i'm gonna link that with <?php echo "$accounttype"; ?><br />

Comment: It will be work, but better try `<?php echo $accounttype; ?><br />`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think that answere my question so long.